# Products of short elements in a field

Tags: nt.number-theory, fields

Consider a field $F$ of characteristic zero. Let $L=F[\alpha]$ be an extension of degree $d.$ We call an element
$$
x=x_0 + x_1 \alpha +\ldots+ x_{d-1}\alpha^{d-1}\in L
$$
*short* if $x_{d-1}=0.$
Under which conditions on $\alpha$ every element in $L^\times$ is a product of short elements?

It is easy to see that every element of $L$ is a quotient of two short elements for $d\geq 3$.

Comment: Oh, thanks, indeed!

Comment: It seems that the definition of short depends on $\alpha$, not only on $F$ and $L$.

Comment: Oh, that's also a good point.

Comment: Do you know an example with $d\geq 3$ for which this does not hold?

Comment: Not explicitly. But for $d=4$ it seems that not every element is (in general) a product of two elements. I would expect that such statement  is true in many cases, but I was not able to find any references.

Comment: Two write an element as a product of two short elements, you're trying to solve a homogeneous equation of degree $d-1$ in $d-1$ variables. For $d=3$ this is possible if $a_1^2/ (a_0a_2)$ is a square and for $d=4$ I think it's smooth and so you're looking for rational points on a genus $1$ curve.

Comment: I also came up with an  elliptic curve for $d=4$ , though I am not sure, where the homogeneous equation that you mention comes from.

Comment: Please do a favor to an aged mathematician with failing eyesight by not using $\alpha$ and $a$ in the same formula.

Comment: @Lubin Oh, sorry, you are totally right!

Comment: You mean "product of two short elements" or "product of several short elements"?

Comment: Of several. It seems that two has no chance to work in general.

Comment: Do you know if the following stronger variant fails? If $d\geq 2$, then any element of $L^\times$ is a product of elements of the form $\alpha-a,a\in F$.

Comment: @Wojowu Not really.

Comment: @Wojowu Here is a counterexample (found with the help of Pari/GP): consider $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$. Then $x=1+\zeta_8-\zeta_8^2$ has norm 9, while an element $a+b\zeta_8$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ has norm $a^4+b^4$ and it is easy to see that the $3$-adic valuation of $a^4+b^4$ is divisible by 4.